# Vuejs transition classes are not applying on Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, vue-transitions

I'm using **VueJs** transition to make a component `appVacancies` slide.

```
<transition name="slide-down" mode="out-in" appear>
  <appVacancies v-if="showVacancies"></appVacancies>
</transition>
```

It's **Vue specific CSS** for transition is

```
// Slide Down animation
.slide-down-active, .slide-down-leave-active {
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.slide-down-enter, .slide-down-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20%);
}
```

On `created()` life-cycle hook I'm just using `setTimeout()` to make `showVacancies` boolean to `true`.

I also have a **fade** animation with similar configuration but that is working.

```
  <transition name="fade">
    <h1 v-if="!showMotion" class="display-2 grad-text mt-4">Welcome!</h1>
  </transition>

   // CSS
  .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  }
  .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Please help.

Comment: Could you show your javaScript please? It sounds like you need troubleshoot inside the appVacancies component and maybe add a placeholder variable to prevent showVacancies from being undefined

Comment: did you ever find the solution?